# Access SIM Service menu using AT Command

Tags: java, c, at-command, ussd

I am working on a project which needs to access "Sim Based Menu", I've read several documents listed with SIM Alliance websites, but I couldn't find any way to do that. Please help me if you know that how to access the SIM based menu(Service menu) using `AT command` or any other way.

I use `SIM900` module for this task.

Service menu

- EZ Bill
- EZ Pay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AT command we can access the "Sim Based Menu". "Sim based menu" has been installed to the Sim card so we have to use the STK(SIM Application Tool Kit) for the access this menu.

AT commands to operate STK functions.

> AT*PSSTK

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at USSD specific AT commands for this. It's not really something to do with your SIM and more to do with your mobile operator. If you know the USSD commands that your operator supports you can send commands like:

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*111*#"
```

You will get then responses from the mobile operator which may or may not include a menu.

Comment: I want ta access the sim service menu like the user Recharge,Ez pay,Bank. But USSD command not use for this. I tried to get help from the network operators but they says that they haven't any ussd code for that.

Comment: Ah is it a sim toolkit application installed upon your SIM card perhaps?

Comment: I think it's may be installed upon SIM, but all of the SIM card has the Topup menu(Reload menu)  I want to access that menu

Comment: Sim toolkit at commands vary depending on modem manufacturer. Which make/model do you have?

Comment: I use SIMCOM SIM900 GPRS+GSM QUAD-Band Module Development Board